# GitHub Repo Size Graph

Tags: github, metrics

I'd like to see a graph of the total size of a repo over time.

(this is useful as it can help to see if poeple are accidentally checking in stuff they shouldn't, like binaries etc.)

The standard github graphs show lots of interesting stuff, but not this simple metric so far as I can see.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered giving a try to the **[GitHub Archive project](http://www.githubarchive.org/)**?

As stated on the home page

> GitHub Archive is a project to **record** the public GitHub timeline, **archive** it, and **make it easily accessible for further analysis**.

GitHub Archive provides downloadable json datasets and also makes its content available via **[Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/)** for easy online analysis (see this **[document](https://github.com/igrigorik/githubarchive.org/tree/master/bigquery#google-bigquery--github-archive)** for more information on this topic and sample queries).

**Note:** GitHub timeline data is available starting February 12, 2011.

### Update:

Provided your repository is private, you may have to fallback to the **[GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)** and consider the `size` member. In order to graph, you'd have to trigger a regularly call to the API and locally store the result.

- *syntax*: `/repos/:user/:repo [GET]`
- *example:* https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2

Comment: Thing is, this is not a public repo. It's an internal organisational one. I want to graph the physical size of the Repo (i.e. how many MB it is to completely clone it) over time. I guess (?) that the Repo iteself may hold this information in it's history.